# ios-charts BalloonMarker.swift Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, charts, xcode8, ios-charts

I'm using ios-Charts from danielgindi/Charts. While adding an object of the BalloonMarker.swift in chartValueSelected:chartView:entry:highlight xcode will generate Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 error.

It indicates that:

```
1.  While type-checking 'draw' at /Users/shenkor/Documents/Apps/Test/iOSCharts/iOSCharts/BalloonMarker.swift:72:19
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/shenkor/Documents/Apps/Test/iOSCharts/iOSCharts/BalloonMarker.swift:158:9 - line:158:61] RangeText="label.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: _drawAttributes)"
```

When I comment the line with "label.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: _drawAttributes)" in BalloonMarker.swift, the error will disappear and the project will build fine except the ballon does not display the any value.

The lines in chartValueSelected:chartView:entry:highlight I used are:

```
let marker: BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(color: UIColor.darkGray, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0), textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0))
marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 75, height: 35)
marker.setLabel(forString: "\(entry.y)")
chartView.marker = marker
chartView.marker?.refreshContent(entry: entry, highlight: highlight)
```

The three lines in setLabel:newLabel:

```
 _drawAttributes[.font] = self.font
 _drawAttributes[.paragraphStyle] = _paragraphStyle
 _drawAttributes[.foregroundColor] = self.textColor
```

also have the error:

```
Ambiguous subscript with base type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]' and index type '_',
```

I'm using xcode8.3.3

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out the problem if there is anyone who's having the same problem. I was using version 4.0.0 of iOS-Charts which is updated for swift4. Since I was using swift 3, I had to get the BallonMarker.swift from v3.0.2 of iOS-Charts which and everything started working.